# find the string and number values corresponding keys

Tags: javascript

I have a column and data array. Trying to map over the column and based on the type of the data, trying to take only string and number, and other values will be discarded.
In the data column -> **ID** is a number and **Starttable** is a string, I want to keep only those.
trying to get the result like

```
[{fieldname: "ID"}, {fieldName: "startTable"}]
```

```
const searchColumnUpdate = (columns, data) =>
  columns.map((x, i) => {
    let columnName =
      typeof x.accessor === "string" ? x.accessor : x?.id || x?.Header;
    if (typeof data[columnName] === "string" || "number") {
      return {
        fieldName: columnName
      };
    }
    return false;
  });

const columns = [
  { Header: "ID", id: "Id", accessor: "ID", sortType: "number" },
  { id: "startTable", Header: "Starttable", sortType: "alphanumeric" },
  { id: "targetTable", Header: "Targettable", sortType: "alphanumeric" },
  { Header: "Joinpath", id: "joinPath", useOnJoinsPage: true, width: 120 }
];
const data = [
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 1,
    Child: null,
    Starttable: "1",
    Targettable: true,
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "3",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "4",
    joinPath: true
  }
];

console.log(searchColumnUpdate(columns, data));
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output based on the given `columns` and `data` you used in your example?  I feel like `[{fieldname: 'ID'}, {fieldName: "startTable"}]` isn't really the entire final result you want.  I could be mistaken though.  Please clarify.

Comment: I am looking for [{fieldname: 'ID'}, {fieldName: "startTable"}]
that's correct

Comment: `["string", "number"].includes(typeof data[columnName])`

Comment: `data` is an array, so `data[columnName]` makes no sense (the array doesn't have any named properties like that.)  Maybe you meant `data[0][columnName]` to just check the type of the data in the first row of data (first element of the `data` array), assuming the data types are homogeneous?

Comment: I am trying this way, it's a mistake for me, but trying to get the output

Answer (score 0):

After fixing some minor typos in your `sel` array (spelling of "fieldname" and "Starttable") the following one-liner should do the trick:

```
const res=data.map(el=>Object.fromEntries(sel.map(({fieldname})=>[fieldname,el[fieldname]])));
```

Here the whole thing as a snippet:

```js
const columns = [
  { id: "Id", Header: "ID", accessor: "ID", sortType: "number" },
  { id: "startTable", Header: "Starttable", sortType: "alphanumeric" },
  { id: "targetTable", Header: "Targettable", sortType: "alphanumeric" },
  { Header: "Joinpath", id: "joinPath", useOnJoinsPage: true, width: 120 }
],
  sel = [{fieldname: "ID"}, {fieldname: "Starttable"}],
  data = [
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 1,
    Child: null,
    Starttable: "1",
    Targettable: true,
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "3",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "4",
    joinPath: true
  }
];

const res=data.map(el=>Object.fromEntries(sel.map(({fieldname})=>[fieldname,el[fieldname]])));

console.log(res)
```

**UPDATE**

It seems I misunderstood your question. As you really want the array `sel` to be the output - and it should - according to your requirements look like:

```
sel = [{fieldname: "ID"}, {fieldname: "Starttable"}, {fieldname: "Guid"}]
```

because `Guid` is also of type "string" - then you can do it like shown below:

```js
const data = [
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 1,
    Child: null,
    Starttable: "1",
    Targettable: true,
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "2",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "3",
    joinPath: true
  },
  {
    Guid: "0280cf7a-af6a-40af-9bc4-73c14c8f4fa7",
    ID: 2,
    Child: null,
    Targettable: true,
    Starttable: "4",
    joinPath: true
  }
];

const res=Object.keys(data.reduce((a,c)=>{
 Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v])=>{
  if(["number","string"].includes(typeof v)) a[k]=1;
 });
 return a;
}, {})).map(k=>({fieldname:k}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hello,
Actually I am trying to find the sel, desired output is [{fieldname: "ID"}, {fieldname: "Starttable"}],